# SQL Server query LIKE doesn't work for string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, nvarchar

I want to retrieve all the rows that their Label (nvarchar(1000)) has 'obama family', when I enter:

```
WHERE Label LIKE '%Obama family%'
```

It gives the row as this.

[image]

Now I want only the row that its label is 'obama family'

I tried these and all of them return empty results:

```
WHERE LOWER(Label) LIKE LOWER('Obama family')
WHERE LOWER(Label) = LOWER('Obama family')
WHERE Label LIKE 'Obama family'
WHERE Label = 'Obama family'
WHERE Label LIKE N'Obama family'
WHERE Label = N'Obama family'
```

I tried this:

```
Update [Wiki].[dbo].[Page] set [label] = RTRIM(LTRIM([label]))
```

and applied the queries again, still it returns empty.

Comment: `I want only the row that its label is 'obama family'`.  Then don't use `LIKE` use equal `=`

Comment: If this is SQL Server, use `RTRIM(LTRIM(Label))`

Comment: Try it `LTRIM(RTRIM(Label))=`

Comment: `LABEL LIKE '%Obama family%'` means "all of the rows where the LABEL column has anything containing 'Obama family'". If you want the rows that are exactly 'obama family', just use `'obama family'` without the percent signs (and with a lower case 'o'), and use '=' instead of 'LIKE'. This is basic SQL; you should find a tutorial or read a book.

Comment: Try WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Label))) = 'obama family'.

Comment: LTRIM(RTRIM(Label))='obama family' returned empty too.

Comment: WHERE LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Label))) = 'obama family' returned empty.

Comment: In the SQL Server results grid, try copying the cell you're trying to match (the `values` field that contains 'Obama Family'), and paste it into a text editor. Does it show anything peculiar? What happens when you use the text editor's functions to search for spaces? I've seen situations like this before, where a text field contains an odd character that looks like a space but isn't.

Comment: If you copied the value from HTML, often there are non-breaking space characters in there somewhere..  Look at each byte in the string.

Comment: Many thanks guys, you are right. With som ehelp, I tried this: SELECT CONVERT(Binary(20), label, 0) AS 'Char to Binary' from [page] where label like 'obama family%' and I got this: 0x4F00620061006D0061002000460061006D0069006C0079000A. '000A' is newline or '\n'. I am getting a backup on my database. then I want to try this: UPDATE [page] 
 Set [label] = REPLACE(REPLACE([label], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')

Answer (score 0):

--for 'obama family' use
select lable from tablename 
where lable COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'obama family'

--for 'Obama Family' use
select lable from tablename 
where lable COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'Obama Family'

--for 'obama Family' use
select lable from tablename 
where lable COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'obama Family'

--for 'Obama family' use
select lable from tablename 
where lable COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'Obama family'

Comment: I found out that there is a newline at the end of the label, so I executed this: UPDATE [page] Set [label] = REPLACE(REPLACE([label], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), and now the old version of the queries that I mentioned in the question are running properly, so I'm not sure if you're method would have worked then :) Thank you anyway.